# How to build OpenCV with contrib module?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, building

I'm trying to build OpenCV 4.4 with contrib module latest version. Even I use the related CMake command, contrib module is not built with OpenCV. Also, I view the all of lib and include files of OpenCV after building, but there are no contrib files. I use this to build:

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/goktug/programs/opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

Additionaly, I tried to build those with the same version number which is 3.4, but result is the same. Also, I use cmake-gui to do this, but result is the same. How to build OpenCV with contrib module?

```
-- Detected processor: x86_64
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- The imported target "openjp2_static" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.a"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "openjpip" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjpip.so.2.3.0"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "openjpip_server" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjpip_server.a"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "opj_decompress" references the file
   "/usr/bin/opj_decompress"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "opj_compress" references the file
   "/usr/bin/opj_compress"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "opj_dump" references the file
   "/usr/bin/opj_dump"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "opj_jpip_addxml" references the file
   "/usr/bin/opj_jpip_addxml"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "opj_server" references the file
   "/usr/bin/opj_server"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "opj_dec_server" references the file
   "/usr/bin/opj_dec_server"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "opj_jpip_transcode" references the file
   "/usr/bin/opj_jpip_transcode"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "opj_jpip_test" references the file
   "/usr/bin/opj_jpip_test"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1/OpenJPEGTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- Found system OpenJPEG: openjp2 (found version "")
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
-- found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2020.0.0 [2020.0.0 Gold]
-- at: /home/goktug/programs/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
-- found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2020.0.0
-- at: /home/goktug/programs/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
-- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing: Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Found VTK 7.1.0 (/usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/UseVTK.cmake)
-- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /home/goktug/programs/opencv/build/python_loader
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   NO
-- Glog:   YES
-- freetype2:   YES (ver 21.0.15)
-- harfbuzz:    YES (ver 1.7.2)
-- Julia not found. Not compiling Julia Bindings. 
-- Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
-- CERES support is disabled. Ceres Solver for reconstruction API is required.
-- Checking for module 'tesseract'
--   No package 'tesseract' found
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Allocator metrics storage type: 'long long'
-- Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /home/goktug/programs/opencv/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
-- opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
-- rgbd: CERES support is disabled. Ceres Solver is Required for Posegraph optimization
-- CERES support is disabled. Ceres Solver for reconstruction API is required.
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.1-dev =====================================
--   Version control:               4.5.1-29-gba3f150b14
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/goktug/programs/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     4.5.1-2-g6d5f4404
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2020-12-27T13:27:39Z
--     Host:                        Linux 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.18.1
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (17 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (7 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ standard:                11
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 7.5.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 alphamat aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python2 python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency sfm shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab viz xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv java julia matlab ovis
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.22.30)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.56.4)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     VTK support:                 YES (ver 7.1.0)
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.34)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.9)
--     JPEG 2000:                   OpenJPEG (ver 2.3.0)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2_2)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (57.107.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (57.83.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (55.78.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (4.8.100)
--       avresample:                YES (3.7.0)
--     GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.5)
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
--            at:                   /home/goktug/programs/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
--               at:                /home/goktug/programs/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.7)
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/goktug/programs/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.17)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.17)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.3)
--     install path:                lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/python-2.7
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.6.9)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (ver 3.6.9)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.19.2)
--     install path:                lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/goktug/programs/opencv/build
```

I think CMake generates the proper make file because those lines of the output:

```
Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/goktug/programs/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     4.5.1-2-g6d5f4404
```

Comment: what is the output of cmake's configure step?

Comment: I added the output CMake configuration step.

Comment: the `To be built:` line tells me that you successfully told cmake where to find the contrib modules. the generated project files/makefiles *should* build the modules listed. at least the cmake step doesn't prevent it.